# Restriction of '@' in php

Tags: php

Problem in restricting "@" in username of signup form.
I am creating a website where i want to know how to restrict "@" in php.
I tried preg replace

```
preg_replace('/@/', '@', $username);
```

but it is not working. What is the appropriate 'preg_replace' value to restrict '@' in php.

Comment: Do you want to check the presence of @, or replace/remove all occurences of @ ?

Comment: i want to check if '@' is there? if yes then i will show an error ,"Username cant contain @";

Comment: For what it's worth, your code is "replace all occurrences of `@` with `@`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str_replace preg_replace to **remove** all ocurrencies of the @ symbol

All of these are essentially equivalent.

```
$username = str_replace('@','',$username);
$username = preg_replace('/@/','',$username);
$username = preg_replace('/[^@']/', '', $username);
```

The last one can take a list of restricted characters within the square brackets

If you want to just check for an @ symbol, I would use `strpos` instead

```
if(strpos($username, '@') !== false){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check the presence of a substring, you can use [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-contains.php)

```
$username = $_POST['username']; //or whatever source
if (str_contains($username, '@')) {
    throw new \Exception('Username cant contain @'); //or whatever expected behavior
}
```